# Mongoose create multiple documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know in the latest version of Mongoose you can pass multiple documents to the create method, or even better in my case an array of documents.

```
var array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }];
Candy.create(array, function (err, jellybean, snickers) {
    if (err) // ...
});
```

My problem is that the size of the array is dynamic so in the callback it would be helpful to have an array of the created objects.

```
var array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }, ..... {type: 'N candie'}];
Candy.create(array, function (err, candies) {
    if (err) // ...

    candies.forEach(function(candy) {
       // do some stuff with candies
    });
});
```

Not in the documentation, but is something like this possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can access the variable list of parameters to your callback via [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).  So you could do something like:

```
Candy.create(array, function (err) {
    if (err) // ...

    for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
        var candy = arguments[i];
        // do some stuff with candy
    }
});
```

Comment: Haha, forgot all about that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 50):

With [Mongoose v5.1.5](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), we can use **insertMany()** method with array passed.

```
const array = [
    {firstName: "Jelly", lastName: "Bean"},
    {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
];

Model.insertMany(array)
    .then(function (docs) {
        response.json(docs);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        response.status(500).send(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2582) on GitHub, Mongoose 3.9 and 4.0 will return an array if you supply an array and a spread of arguments if you supply a spread when using `create()`.

Answer (score 7):

Since Mongoose v5 you can use `insertMany`
According to [the mongoose site](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) it is faster than `.create()`:

> Shortcut for validating an array of documents and inserting them into
> MongoDB if they're all valid. This function is faster than `.create()`
> because it only sends one operation to the server, rather than one for
> each document.

Complete example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
  
// Database connection 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}); 
  
// User model 
const User = mongoose.model('User', { 
    name: { type: String }, 
    age: { type: Number } 
}); 


// Function call, here is your snippet
User.insertMany([ 
    { name: 'Gourav', age: 20}, 
    { name: 'Kartik', age: 20}, 
    { name: 'Niharika', age: 20} 
]).then(function(){ 
    console.log("Data inserted")  // Success 
}).catch(function(error){ 
    console.log(error)      // Failure 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

by `insert` function of collection db,
example:

```
Model.collection.insert(array, (err, list) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('list:', list);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserts without timestamp by default since you are doing this directly to database

```
Model.collection.insertOne({}, callback);
Model.collection.insertMany([], callback);
```

Saves to database with timestamp accepts array or object

```
Model.create([])
```