# mongoose schema used as an array in another schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using express 4.9.0, mongoose 3.8.24, and MongoDB 2.6.8

I have two schemas the first is to provide questions, and the second schema is to provide a number of possible choices and the opportunity for voting on there favourite answer.

My problem is the choices are not going into the database and hence I cannot display them.

I have created the following code:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ChoiceSchema = new Schema({
    choice: String,
    vote: Number
});

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question: String,
    choices: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Choices'}],
    pub_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
var QuestionModel = mongoose.model('question', QuestionSchema);
var ChoiceModel = mongoose.model('Choices', ChoiceSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/polls');

var question = new QuestionModel({
    question: "Which colour do you like best?"
});
question.save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    var choices = new ChoiceModel({choices: [{choice: "red", vote: 0}, 
                                {choice: "green", vote: 0}, 
                                {choice: "blue", vote: 0}]});
    choices.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Further down the page I try to get the results but the choices are not going into the mongodb Database.

```
app.get('/choice', function(req, res) {
    QuestionModel
    .findOne({ question: "Which colour do you like best?"})
    .populate('choices')
    .exec(function(err, question){
        if (err) throw err;
        // need some code here to display the answers not sure what to put
    });
    res.send("Hello World"); // This is just to stop express from hanging
});
```

If I inspect MongoDB from the command line I have two collections.
choices, questions

```
> db.choices.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5502d6612c682ed217b62092"), "__v" : 0 }

> db.questions.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5502d6612c682ed217b62091"),
    "question" : "Which colour do you like best?",
    "pub_date" : ISODate("2015-03-13T12:21:53.564Z"),
    "choices" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

As you can see above the choices should have three colours red, green and blue and each colour should have a vote set 0.
How can I make it so choices appears correctly in the Database?
How can I display the results in Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if the problem has to do with how you're trying to add the choices to their collection:

```
var choices = new ChoiceModel({choices: [{choice: "red", vote: 0}, 
                              {choice: "green", vote: 0}, 
                              {choice: "blue", vote: 0}]});
```

1. It doesn't seem to match how you've setup your Choices Schema
2. I'm not sure mongoose's API allows you to create multiple documents with `new Model()` The [mongoose API for Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model) seems to suggest that you can pass a single object of values to it for the new document you're creating.

If you want to create multiple documents in one go, [Mongoose's Model#create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) is perhaps what you're looking for:

```
var choices = [{choice: "red", vote: 0}, 
               {choice: "green", vote: 0}, 
               {choice: "blue", vote: 0}];
ChoiceModel.create(choices, function (err, jellybean, snickers) {
    if (err) // ...
    /* your choices have been stored to DB. No need to call .save() */
});
```

You might find this related question useful: [Mongoose create multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400029/mongoose-create-multiple-documents)

Comment: Thankyou Marco now have the follow:\nchoiceData = [{choice: "red", vote: 0}, {choice: "green", vote: 0}, {choice: "blue"}];
ChoiceModel.create(choiceData, function () {
    var mgTypes = mongoose.Types,
        args = arguments;
    if (args[0]) throw err;
    var question = QuestionModel({
        question: "Which colour do like best?",
        choices: [mgTypes.ObjectId(args[1]._id), mgTypes.ObjectId(args[2]._id), mgTypes.ObjectId(args[3]._id)]
    });
    question.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});